# jQuery/PHP/Ajay: hot to manage an associative array from PHP with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In a form, after the user has selected a field from a select menù I would like the following field to be automatically filled with the relative data and this is what I have done up to now:

```
<?php

  $deep="";
  include($deep."include/head.php");
  if (isset($_POST["tipologia"])) {

      $impostazione = $sistema->impostazioni->impostazioneInfo("SOLO_DORMIRE");
      echo $impostazione;

  }

?>
```

where impostazioneInfo is:

```
public function impostazioneInfo($t) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->config->table_impostazioni." WHERE tipologia='".$t."'");
    $v = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $tmp = array(
        'id'=>$v['id'],
        'tipologia'=>$v['tipologia'],
        'persone1'=>$v['persone1'],
        'persone2'=>$v['persone2'],
        'persone3'=>$v['persone3'],
        'persone4'=>$v['persone4'],
        'persone5'=>$v['persone5'],
        'persone6'=>$v['persone6'],
        'inizio_ferragosto'=>$v['inizio_ferragosto'],
        'fine_ferragosto'=>$v['fine_ferragosto'],
        'inizio_capodanno'=>$v['inizio_capodanno'],
        'fine_capodanno'=>$v['fine_capodanno'],
        'capodanno2'=>$v['capodanno2'],
        'capodanno3'=>$v['capodanno3'],
        'capodanno4'=>$v['capodanno4'],
        'capodanno5'=>$v['capodanno5'],
        'capodanno6'=>$v['capodanno6'],
        'ferragosto2'=>$v['ferragosto2'],
        'ferragosto3'=>$v['ferragosto3'],
        'ferragosto4'=>$v['ferragosto4'],
        'ferragosto5'=>$v['ferragosto5'],
        'ferragosto6'=>$v['ferragosto6'],
        'ragazzi'=>$v['ragazzi'],
        'ragazzi_ferragosto'=>$v['ragazzi_ferragosto'],
        'ragazzi_capodanno'=>$v['ragazzi_capodanno'],
        'pers_per_chalet'=>$v['pers_per_chalet']
    );

return $tmp;
```

and finally in the main page this is what I have inside the jQuery ready function:

```
jQuery("#tipologia").on('change', function() {

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "get_databy_type.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {tipologia: jQuery("#tipologia").val()},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });


}
```

and I would expect the alert to print the result array from php but I get a lot of things I don't know. How can I retrieve all the field so that I can populate the rest of the html form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on server side to send the data in `json` format. And set the `dataType` to `json` in `ajax` configuration.

Server side:

```
echo json_encode($impostazione);
```

Client Side:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "get_databy_type.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        tipologia: jQuery("#tipologia").val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    success: function(data) { // data is json object
        alert(data.id); // Alert id from the object
    }
});
```

Comment: @LoryLory What is the `response` you got from  `ajax`, see in network tab of `console`

Comment: Either `echo json_encode($impostazione);` or `return json_encode(tmp);`. Also, before the echo, put in a `header('Content-Type: application/json');` (could be his error, not sure)

Comment: I have tried all that you said but still nothing is alerted... in the network tab I don't see anything useful...

Comment: If you open the get_databy_type.php directly, do you see an php error? Maybe add an error callback to see whether or not the request failed.

Comment: Ok, I think I have solved the problem. First of all I had to call php function header('Content-Type: application/json')...this crashed with another header I enclose by default in each php page: I learnt that the json header must be the only one when maling an ajax call to a php program!!!